# How to concat the object is useState array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-state

I have the useState varible. I want to concat the value with new object.

```
const [dates,setDates] = useState(["Mon","Sun"])
```

rules:
1.If the date exist with isSelected flag then make as false

```
[{day:"mon",isSelected:false}]
```

otherwise, make as,

```
[{day:"mon",isSelected:true}]
```

my function below,

```
const handleDay = (day) => {
  setDates((x) => {
    x.map((v) => {
      if (day === v.day && v.isSelected) {
        v.isSelected = true;
        return {
          v,
        };
      } else {
        return {
          day,
          isSelected: true,
        };
      }
    });
  });
};

handleDay('mon');
```

expected output

```
[{day:"mon",isSelected:true}, 'Sun']
```

but I got this,

```
 [{
    "day": "Mon",
    "isSelected": true
 }, {
    "day": "Mon",
    "isSelected": true
 }]
```

Comment: so `["Mon","Sun"]` will become eg `[{day:"mon",isSelected:false}]` or `[{day:"mon",isSelected:false}, 'Sun']`?

Comment: [{day:"mon",isSelected:false}, 'Sun'] this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your `map` code with this

```
arr.map(v => {
  if (day === v.day || day === v) {
    return {
      day: v.day ? v.day : v,
      isSelected: !v.isSelected
    };
  } else {
    return v
  }
});
```

```js
let arr = ["Mon", "Sun"]

const handleDay = day => {
  let arr2 =  
    arr.map(v => {
      if (day === v.day || day === v) {
        return {
          day: v.day ? v.day : v,
          isSelected: !v.isSelected
        };
      } else {
        return v
      }
    });
    
    return arr2;
};

console.log(handleDay('Mon'));
arr = handleDay('Mon');
console.log(handleDay('Mon'));
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understan your requirements, `handleDay`should look like this:

```
const handleDay = (day) => {
  setDates((x) => {
    return x.map((v) => {
      if (day === v.day && v.isSelected) {
        v.isSelected = false;
        return {
          v,
        };
      } else {
        return day
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

piotrruss had it almost correct.

```js
const handleDay = (day) => {
  setDates((x) => {
    return x.map((v) => {
      if (day === v || day === v.day) {
        return {
          day,
          isSelected: !v.isSelected,
        };
      } else {
        return v;
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concat your object with spread operator also.

```
const handleDay = (day) => {
setDates((x) => {
    return x.map((v) => {
      if (day === v.day && v.isSelected) {
        v.isSelected = false;
        return {
          v,
        };
      } else {
        return day
      }
    });
  });
};
```